# Istanbul code coverage - if path is not taken

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, istanbul

The following is the function for which find the attached Istanbul coverage report.

```
export function getControlFromId(controlId, ancestorControl) {
  if (!(controlId && ancestorControl)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  if (controlId === ancestorControl.id) {
    return ancestorControl;
  }

  if (ancestorControl.controls) {
    for (const control of ancestorControl.controls) {
      const result = getControlFromId(controlId, control);
      if (result) {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

[image: Istanbul coverage report]

Problem: Why it says if-path is not taken? The image clearly shows lines in if loop are executed.

Sample test data:

```
const ancestorControl = {
        name: 'form',
        controls: [
          {
            name: 'Section',
            id: 1,
          },
        ],
      };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, it shows that your if condition is partially executed which means that you are testing the positive flow where `ancestorControl.controls` is available.

You might be missing the test case where `ancestorControl.controls` is not available.

Comment: Oh yes! Even though I considered that case, gave wrong test data. Thanks.